# jQuery: Add class to a parent div if it contains an empty child span

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to add a class ".is-empty" to my div.additional-property if it contains an empty span. In this example the first span is empty, the second span contains values. The entire element should be hidden if one of these spans is empty.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="widget widget-grid widget-two-col row desc-ean additional-property">
  <div class="widget-inner col-xl-6 widget-prop-xl-3-1 col-lg-6 widget-prop-lg-3-1 col-md-6 widget-prop-md-3-1 col-sm-12 widget-prop-sm-3-1 widget-stacked-mobile col-12 widget-prop-3-1 widget-stacked-mobile">
    <div>
      <div class="widget widget-text widget-none test">
        <div class="widget-inner bg-appearance">
          <p><span></span> <br></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-inner col-xl-6 widget-prop-xl-3-1 col-lg-6 widget-prop-lg-3-1 col-md-6 widget-prop-md-3-1 col-sm-12 widget-prop-sm-3-1 col-12 widget-prop-3-1">
    <div>
      <div class="widget widget-text widget-none desc-ean__code">
        <div class="widget-inner bg-appearance">
          <p><span>408</span> mm<br></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to use jQuery but I'm completely struggling right now.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: If you haven't learned JavaScript yet, I'd start learning from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) (free, ads on the sides) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) (free, no ads, a bit more technical).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".additional-property span").each(function(){ 
    if($(this).html().trim()==""){
        $(this).closest(".additional-property").addClass("is-empty");
    }
});
```

This JQuery code loops through all spans inside divs with the class .additional-property, checks if the span is empty, and if yes it adds the class .is-empty to the according parent div with class .additional-property.

Comment: You should probably include what exactly your code does to have a likelier chance of getting upvotes/an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

- First check every span under `.additional-property` using Jquery `each` function.
- Check every span is empty or not using `trim` function.
- add `is-empty` class using `parent()` to closest div.

```js
$(".additional-property span").each(function(){ 
    if($(this).html().trim()==""){
        $(this).parent().addClass("is-empty");
    }
});
```

```css
.is-empty{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget widget-grid widget-two-col row desc-ean additional-property">
  <div class="widget-inner col-xl-6 widget-prop-xl-3-1 col-lg-6 widget-prop-lg-3-1 col-md-6 widget-prop-md-3-1 col-sm-12 widget-prop-sm-3-1 widget-stacked-mobile col-12 widget-prop-3-1 widget-stacked-mobile">
    <div>
      <div class="widget widget-text widget-none test">
        <div class="widget-inner bg-appearance">
          <p><span></span> <br></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-inner col-xl-6 widget-prop-xl-3-1 col-lg-6 widget-prop-lg-3-1 col-md-6 widget-prop-md-3-1 col-sm-12 widget-prop-sm-3-1 col-12 widget-prop-3-1">
    <div>
      <div class="widget widget-text widget-none desc-ean__code">
        <div class="widget-inner bg-appearance">
          <p><span>408</span> mm<br></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```